# How to import single-column CSV as an array in R? (values importing as column names)

Tags: r, csv

I have an "upside down" comma separated list of 1000 single-digit integers. What I'm trying to do is produce a count of each integer, and a histogram showing their distribution.

e.g. `3,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,0,3,1,2,0,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,0,0,1,....`

However, when I `read.csv()`, R produces a data frame with 0 observations of 1000 variables, and my numbers as column names.

How can I bring in this unconventional data format as a single column data-frame/array? I have tried `x <- x[-1, ]`

TIA!

Comment: Probably best to read it in as a vector using `scan("filename.csv", sep = ",")`.

Comment: Thank you! scan() %>% as.data.frame() solves my issue!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, `scan("filename.csv", sep = ",")` is the way to go here.

The following code produces a histogram and prints out the proportion of each value in the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

x = scan("text.csv", sep=",")
N = length(x)
df <- as.data.frame(x)
ggplot(df) + geom_histogram(aes(x=x))
count(df, x) %>% mutate(n=n/N)
```

Output:

```
  x     n
1 0 0.171
2 1 0.352
3 2 0.319
4 3 0.158
```

[image: Uneven histogram]

...Confirming my suspicion that `Math.round(Math.random() * N)` in JS is not uniform, and under-represents the borders (in this case 0 and 3), due to rounding e.g. 0.6 up to 1. And of course, all of this was in vein, because I should have been using **Math.floor()** this whole time! :)

Running the same test, with Math.floor() instead of Math.round(), truncates the top number but produces a far more even result:

[image: Uniform histogram]